# Getting Data Using formData Parameters in get Request in React

Tags: reactjs

var formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append('userid', '1')

```
 axios
  .get('<APIURL>'', formdata, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  })
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

AND IT GIVES ME THIS ERROR

Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:99)